# simple n x n matrix in python not working

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I use this to create 4x4 matrix of 'x':

```
listof=[] #table
nic=[] #row
max = 4 #tabele size
nic = ['x']*max #row of x-es
listof = [nic]*max #table of rows
print(listof) #it looks ok
listof[1][1] ="o" #changing one x to o
print(listof) # wrong since all rows have o on index 1
```

?how come?

BTW: I know it Works if I use:

```
listof = [["x" for x in range(max)] for y in range(max)]
```

But what is wrong with the code above?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `listof` ends up consisting of four references *to the same list*. As a result, when you change an element in one row, it changes in all rows.